# Creating 'mpint' value in Java (The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol Architecture - RFC 4251)

Tags: java, ssh

I'm trying to create `mpint` string using BigInteger as specified in [RFC4251](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt):

> mpint
>
> Represents multiple precision integers in two's complement format,
>    stored as a string, 8 bits per byte, MSB first.  Negative numbers
>    have the value 1 as the most significant bit of the first byte of
>    the data partition.  If the most significant bit would be set for
>    a positive number, the number MUST be preceded by a zero byte.
>    Unnecessary leading bytes with the value 0 or 255 MUST NOT be
>    included.  The value zero MUST be stored as a string with zero
>    bytes of data.
>
> By convention, a number that is used in modular computations in
>    Z_n SHOULD be represented in the range 0 <= x < n.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>      value (hex)        representation (hex)
>      -----------        --------------------
>      0                  00 00 00 00
>      9a378f9b2e332a7    00 00 00 08 09 a3 78 f9 b2 e3 32 a7
>      80                 00 00 00 02 00 80
>      -1234              00 00 00 02 ed cc
>      -deadbeef          00 00 00 05 ff 21 52 41 11
> ```

Everything almost clear, but how to explain "*Unnecessary leading bytes with the value 0 or 255 MUST NOT be included.*"?

And the second question is about this line: *"By convention, a number that is used in modular computations in Z_n SHOULD be represented in the range 0 <= x < n."*. How to explain it?

**EDIT:**

My first suggestion is:

```
/**
 * Write 'mpint' to output stream including length.
 *
 * @param dos output stream
 * @param bi the value to be written
 */
public static void writeMPInt(DataOutputStream dos, BigInteger bi) throws IOException {

    byte[] twos = bi.toByteArray();

    dos.writeInt(twos.length);
    dos.write(twos);
}
```

Does this method is valid according mentioned above rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unnecessary leading bytes with the value 0 or 255 MUST NOT be included.

**Do not** pad the front of numbers with extra `00` or `ff` bytes.

1. `80` stored as `00 00 00 03 00 00 80` has an extra leading `00` byte.
2. `-deadbeef` stored as `00 00 00 06 ff ff 21 52 41 11` has an extra leading `ff` byte.

In both cases, the numbers are technically correct but have unnecessary leading bytes.

---

> By convention, a number that is used in modular computations in Z_n SHOULD be represented in the range 0 <= x < n.

Z_n is an ASCII way of writing the bold math notation for [integers modulo *n*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wt9e.png). ([see Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic))

This means, you **should not** store a number `x` greater than the modulus `n` to be used, or less than zero.

1. You wish to store the number 123.
2. You know that number will be modulo 100 for sure. That is, `123 % 100`.
3. You should store 23 instead.

---

> Does this method is valid according mentioned above rules?

No, `write()` does not check if the values in your byte array conform to the above rules.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully agree with Jay Jun and because I did not understand it the first time I will try to give a different (hopefully simpler) answer (in code):

> Unnecessary leading bytes with the value 0 or 255 MUST NOT be included.

The following code snippet will output the long (8 bytes) for the values: 0x80 and -0xdeadbeef

```
    //long has 8 bytes
    long l = 0x80L;
    System.out.println("0x80 = "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>56) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>48) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>40) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>32) & 0xFF)+String.format("%02X ", (l>>24) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>16) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>8) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l) & 0xFF));
    l = -0xdeadbeefL;
    System.out.println("-0xdeadbeef = "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>56) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>48) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>40) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>32) & 0xFF)+String.format("%02X ", (l>>24) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>16) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l>>8) & 0xFF)+" "+String.format("%02X ", (l) & 0xFF));
```

The output is:

```
0x80L = 00  00  00  00 00  00  00  80 
-0xdeadbeefL = FF  FF  FF  FF 21  52  41  11
```

As we can see 0x80L is positive and has 7 leading 0 bytes but only 6 must not be included because the leading bit of 80 (binary value = 10000000) is 1 and therefore according to:

> If the most significant bit would be set for a positive number, the number MUST be preceded by a zero byte

we have to precede 0x80 with one 0-byte. The result is therefore "00 80".

Vice versa for -0xdeadbeef we have 4 leading 255 bytes but only 3 must not be included because the most significant bit of "21" is "0" and therefore we need 1 leading 255 byte before "21  52  41  11" and the result is "ff 21 42 41 11"

All this leading byte problematic is handled when using BigInteger:

```
    byteArray = new byte[]{(byte) 0x80};
    bigInteger = new BigInteger(+1, byteArray);
    byteArray = bigInteger.toByteArray();
    byteArray = new byte[]{(byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0xef};
    bigInteger = new BigInteger(-1, byteArray);
    byteArray = bigInteger.toByteArray();
```

So coming back to the question:

> Does this method is valid according mentioned above rules?

**I would say yes**.

PS: the only rule that BigInteger is not handling correctly is:

> The value zero MUST be stored as a string with zero bytes of data

```
    byteArray = new byte[]{};
    bigInteger = new BigInteger(0, byteArray);
    byteArray = bigInteger.toByteArray();
```

will actually return 1 byte with the value of 0 instead of an empty array.